# Rails: using set_table_name to join across different databases on the same mysql server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

For legacy reasons, my model's tables are stored in two different databases on the same MySQL server.  At first I just used `establish_connection` to specify the second database on the models that used it.  However, when I established a `has_many :through` connection between two models in different databases, it blew up because MySQL cannot JOIN across two different servers.   Then I noticed on the interwebs that I could use `set_table_name 'other_database.foos'` instead of using `establish_connection`.

This mostly works, but `table_exists?` always returns false even when the table does exist, and a couple of the plugins I'm using use that function extensively.

Is this a bug in `table_exists?`, or am I misusing `set_table_name`?   Is there another way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Thank  you for that question, it helped me to resolve issue which was causing I was pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

`table_exists?` does the following:

```
def table_exists?(table_name)
  tables.include?(table_name.to_s)
end
```

Where tables is an array of the table names for the established connection (defined in `databases.yml`). So if you call `table_exists?('database.table_name')` or `table_exists?('table_name_from_second_database')` then it will always return false.

The only way around this would be to monkey patch `table_exists?` or the function that loads the `tables` array. See the [api docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements) to see where to start with the patching.

Good Luck!